# Seconds not being calculated properly based on angle of rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

jsFiddle: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaBrains/urysma8d/6/)

As per fiddle or snippet below, you can see I have big circle containing 5 small circles. In the below image I gave numbers to all circles. Now in fiddle when you try to rotate the small circle 1, it works properly and increase the number in correct way (displayed at bottom left).

Now try to rotate other circles one bye one (2,3,4,5) and you will see the number is showing negative values which is not correct, it should always display the correct seconds as it is being rotated.

I had updated the linear scale in code:
`var timeScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 360]).domain([0, 60]);` based on each circle's start position but it's not working.

Can anyone please help me out to solve this?

[image]

```js
var values = [
        {value: 33, label: 'A'},
        {value: 33, label: 'B'},
        {value: 33, label: 'C'},
        {value: 33, label: 'D'},
        {value: 33, label: 'E'}
    ];
    var total = 0;
    var dragging = null;
    var circleTransform;
    var circleCoordinates;

    values.forEach(function (d) {
        d.absoluteValue = total;
        total += d.value;
    });

    var height = 300, width = 300, margin = {top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20};
    var radius = (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) / 2;

    var parent = d3.select('.ring-input').append('svg')
        .attr({
            height: height,
            width: width
        }).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    var angularScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 360]).domain([0, total]);
    var timeScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 360]).domain([0, 60]);

    var ring = parent.append('g').attr('id', 'rim').attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
    ring.append('circle').attr({
        r: radius,
        'class': 'ring'
    })

    var handles = parent.append('g').attr('id', 'handles').attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')');
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function (d) {
            return d;
        })
        .on("dragstart", function () {
            circleTransform = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform"));
            circleCoordinates = circleTransform.translate;
        })
        .on("drag", dragmove)
        .on('dragend', function () {
            d3.select(this)
                .classed('active', false)
                .attr({
                    transform: circleTransform
                });
            document.getElementById('estimated-time').innerHTML = 0;
        });

    //position the handles based on the input values
    function drawHandles() {
        var join = handles.selectAll('circle').data(values);
        join.enter()
            .append('circle').attr({
            r: 10,
            'class': 'handle'
        }).on("mouseover", function () {
            d3.select(this).classed('active', true);
        })
            .on("mouseout", function () {
                d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
            })
            .call(drag);

        join.attr({
            transform: function (d) {
                return 'rotate(' + angularScale(d.absoluteValue) + ') translate(' + radius + ',0)'
            }
        })
    }

    drawHandles();

    function dragmove(d, i) {
        d3.select(this).classed('active', true);
        var coordinates = d3.mouse(parent.node());
        var x = coordinates[0] - radius;
        var y = coordinates[1] - radius;
        var newAngle = Math.atan2(y, x) * 57.2957795;
        if (newAngle < 0) {
            newAngle = 360 + newAngle;
        }
        d.absoluteValue = angularScale.invert(newAngle);

        var startAngle = Math.atan2(circleCoordinates[1], circleCoordinates[0]) * 57.2957795;
        if (startAngle < 0) {
            startAngle = 360 + startAngle;
        }
        timeScale.range([startAngle, startAngle + 360]);
        document.getElementById('estimated-time').innerHTML = Math.round(timeScale.invert(newAngle));
        //REDRAW HANDLES
        drawHandles()
    }
```

```css
.handle {
  fill: #FFF;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 4;
  cursor: all-scroll;
}

 .handle.active {
   stroke: #F00;
}

.ring {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   stroke-width: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="ring-input"></div>
<div id="estimated-time">0</div>
```

Comment: You do require to subtract the initial angle of the circle.